# How to run makefile in parallel after using add_custom_target in cmake?

Tags: cmake

I am following [this](https://www.dealii.org/8.4.0/users/cmakelists.html) tutorial to build my project in release and debug mode. Everything works file except when I try to run makefile in parallel using `make debug -j4`. The **warning** I get is `make[4]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add '+' to parent make rule.`

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(debug
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target all
  COMMENT "Switch CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to Debug"
  )

ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(release
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target all
  COMMENT "Switch CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to Release"
  )
```

I was hoping the `make debug -j4 or make release -j4` would work. But apparently it does not.

Answer (score 1):

The target `debug` is a single target that runs a single job that invokes `cmake` to recreate the Makefiles and then has `cmake` invoke `make`.  `-j4` is used to run 4 jobs at a time.  But there isn't four jobs just one. The warning message is from `make` detecting that the child process isn't `make` anymore and cannot interpret the `-j` option.

You need to update the rules to work correctly.

`COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} -j 4 --target all`

This will have`cmake` pass `make` the `-j 4` option when building after all the Makefiles have been updated. Refer to `Build Tool Mode` in the `cmake` manual.

Comment: @mato I've updated it to be `-j 4`. You have to use a variable in the place of the `4` and use the command `cmake -DNUM_JOBS=4 debug`.  Or you could remove the `-j 4` and try `CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL=4 cmake debug`. This should add an environment variable `CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL` before running `cmake`.