# CMake forwarding parallel builds to make when using ExternalProject_Add on a Autotools-generated project

Tags: cmake, makefile, autotools

I'm trying to have CMake to call `make` in parallel mode when using `ExternalProject_Add`, but the [external project](https://www.qemu.org/)'s makefiles aren't being generated by CMake, but with Autotools. I don't want to hard-code the number of jobs, but have it being controlled by CMake.

I'm wrapping the external project with `ExternalProject_Add` like so:

```
find_program(MAKE_COMMAND NAMES make REQUIRED)

ExternalProject_Add(qemu
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    BINARY_DIR ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/qemu/configure --prefix="${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/qemu"
    BUILD_COMMAND ${MAKE_COMMAND} -j16
    INSTALL_COMMAND ${MAKE_COMMAND} install
)
```

I'm calling CMake like so:

```bash
cmake -B~/builds -S~/my_project -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/installs
cmake --build ~/builds -j`nproc`
```

This works really well, the project gets configured, built and installed.

What I noticed though, is that if I change the build command to just `BUILD_COMMAND ${MAKE_COMMAND}`, building the external project takes much longer. For me that means that make isn't using parallel builds. I also don't want to just hard-code a number of parallel builds in the build command because there are other parts being built that are CMake-native.

The [`CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.28/envvar/CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL.html) variable determines the maximum number of parallel jobs CMake will use overall when `-j` is omitted, and I'd the like the exact opposite: to figure out what is the value of `num_jobs` when CMake is called like `cmake --build -jnum_jobs`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54175932/6271889) hard-codes the number of jobs and uses CMake as the generator. I've also checked [this CMake forum post](https://discourse.cmake.org/t/cmake-parallel-build/1838) to no avail.

Any input is welcome! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out [@fdk1342 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54175932/6271889) is the right way to do it. Even though the external project uses Autotools as the generator and not CMake, CMake can build it:

```
ExternalProject_Add(qemu
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    BINARY_DIR ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/qemu/configure --prefix="${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/qemu"
    BUILD_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR} -j
    INSTALL_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR} --target install
)
```